# Status Code validator in Web service consumer in mule

Tags: web-services, soap, timeout, mule

I have three questions...

1. Just like HTTP requester in mule we have success code validator , i want same for web service consumer so that in response if i am getting status code 500 , i want to make it as success scenario ( means it is consider as success state).
2. Also if i want to increase response time out for web service consumer in mule how can i achieve it??
3. Suppose i am using scatter and gather and inside there i placed 3 separate flows , at the end i know scatter-gather will respond as an array than i have to write below logic in Mel expression..how i can do that please advice.

Logic:- if payload[1] && payload[1] && payload[2] == null that return "myvalue" else default payload

Can you please answer for all three question ..

Cheers,
b

Answer (score 0):

1. If you're getting failure response, your exception flow will be triggered.
   You can use catch inside choice strategy and catch a relevant exception and set payload inside catch accordingly.
2. You can proxy your consumer, or your can use deprecated HTTP connector connection configuration, see this.

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/web-service-consumer#proxy-the-web-service-consumer

3. Looks like you want to use if-else condition, for one can use a Groovy script or Choice router.

Hope this helps.

Cheers!